# Disable system download notification from Brave Browser in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, notification, brave

Whenever I download something with Brave Browser I get the system popup notification from the status bar like this (red):

[image]

and underlying i have the popup from the browser itself (green)...

Is there any way of disabling the system notification?
In system settings under `program settings` where there are notification settings for e.g. Thunderbird and other programs I can't even find Brave Browser in the list. Only an entry with `other applications` where I should be able to disable the notifications for all other programs which I don't want!
Frankly even that setting doesn't get rid of the system pop-up...